# Android library and Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-emulator

This question may seems very stupid but I'm really stuck. To run the map on my app on my emulator I need to run with Google Api library and on emulator), but for textview and rest of the stuff I run with Android 4.2.. How can I run the whole app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose "Google APIs" as your SDK target, that includes the full Android API for that level as well.

Thus, if you choose "Google APIs (level 17)", that will include Android 4.2.

Note that in addition to the setting the appropriate API level, you may need additional libraries to support particular Google services.  For example, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for details on adding the maps library, or http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#libs for details on adding the helper libraries for Google Cloud Messaging.

Comment: **For Eclipse users:** While creating the project in eclipse and once you select 'Google APIs' in 'Select Build Target' page you can see an additional text as 'Android + Google Api'.